# How do I create an array in C++ using new and initialize each element?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2008, initialization, new-operator

Without iterating through each element, how do I create an array using new and initialize each element to a certain value?

```
bool* a = new bool[100000];
```

Using VS 2008.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In that case, the only value you can set it to is `false` with:

```
bool* a = new bool[100000]();
```

That said, I'm not sure why you'd think you can't use a loop. They're there for a reason. You should just use the ready-made function `fill` or `fill_n` (depending on taste).

---

Note using `new` "raw" like that is terrible programming practice. Use a `std::vector<bool>`*:

```
std::vector<bool> v;

v.resize(100000);
std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), true); // or false
```

Or:

```
std::vector<bool> v;

v.reserve(100000);
std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(v), 100000, true); // or false
```

*Of course, `std::vector<bool>` happens to break the proper container interface so doesn't actually store `bool`'s. If that's a problem use a `std::vector<char>` instead.

Comment: I was using a vector, but it was way too slow. So I am looking for a faster solution.

But I didn't use fill so I think this may be faster.

Comment: @BSeven: I seriously doubt that your claim is true and that you're in a position where it would matter anyway. Use a `std::vector`, it handles the management for you so you don't get easily avoided leaks. Did you profile your fully completed release-build application and found the results suggested using a `std::vector` was the slowest part of your application? (No.)

Comment: @BSeven: at what point was vector so slow? In release compiles, it should be as fast as a raw array if used properly.

Comment: `struct bool_wrap { bool b; bool_wrap(bool b) : b(b) {} bool_wrap() : b(false) {} operator bool() { return b; } };` so that `std::vector<bool_wrap>` works the way `std::vector<bool>` _should_.

Comment: @Chris: Just make the first constructor's parameter default to `false`, by the way.

Comment: @GMan - Oh, yeah. I _could_ do that.

Comment: @GMan: OK, I got that part working, and it is much faster. But the application is too slow. Is there a good profiler for VS 2008 standard? I installed the stand alone VS profiler, but it is terrible.

Comment: @BSeven: You'll want to ask that as a separate question (after searching for questions about profiles, of course). That said, `std::vector<int>` versus `new int` is seriously a non-issue. Slow-downs come from the approach you take to calculating data, not from slightly different ways of storing data. (And actually non-different, in this case, after optimization.)

Comment: why int * instead of bool * what difference does it make?

Comment: @Saher: `int*` would be an error. :) I'm surprised it's been there for so long without anyone noticing, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to what GMan said above, I believe you can specify an initial value for each value in your vector on construction like this..

```
vector<bool> a (100000, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer the vector approach, but you can also use memset.

Answer (score 1):

If `0 is false` and `1 is true` considered - you can do

```
bool* a = new bool[100];
std::fill_n( a, 100, 1 ); // all bool array elements set to true
std::fill_n( a, 100, 0 ); // all bool array elements set to false
```